# having issues setting up and displaying the sprites in my classes/subclasses in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Hello I am relatively new to creating games/coding so sorry before hand for the multitude of issues I am going to be bringing and the god awful organisation of my code, I'm attempting to have my class' have a function to render themselves into the game instead of using an outside source

```
`class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(Self,):
        super().__init__()
        Self.Image=pygame.image.load('Blank.png').convert_alpha()
        Self.rect=Self.image.get_rect()
        Self.x=x
        Self.y=y
        Self.Screen= screen
        #Self.Width=Width
        #Self.Height=Height
        #Self.Energy=0
        
        

    def BoundryX(entityX):
        if entityX<=0:
            entityX=0
        elif entityX>=600:
            entityX=600
            
    def BoundryY(entityY):
        if entityY<=0:
            entityY=0
        elif entityY>=800:
            entityY=800
        
class Predator(Animal):
    def __init__(Self):
        #super().__init__()
        Self.Img=pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
        Self.PredatorX=0
        Self.PredatorY=0
        Self.Screen= screen
        
        
    def Render(Self,Img,X,Y):
        Self.screen.blit(Img,(X,Y))
        `
```

I'm having issues as it says the class doesn't have the attribute "screen" and I do not know what that means, on a side note what would be the best way to create a function to create more of a set class after they have eaten enough of their food chain as well as a function to remove them as well as organise all of the different sprites(I understand this isn't apart of my main issue so if it doesn't get answer that's fine)

here is the full code: (sorry for any pain caused by my terrible formatting

```
 #imports
    import math
    import random
    import pygame,sys 
    import random
    import pdb
    from pygame.locals  import *
    
    
    timmer=1
    
    
    
    
    class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(Self,):
            super().__init__()
            Self.Image=pygame.image.load('Blank.png').convert_alpha()
            Self.rect=Self.image.get_rect()
            Self.x=x
            Self.y=y
            Self.Screen= screen
            #Self.Width=Width
            #Self.Height=Height
            #Self.Energy=0
            
            
    
        def BoundryX(entityX):
            if entityX<=0:
                entityX=0
            elif entityX>=600:
                entityX=600
                
        def BoundryY(entityY):
            if entityY<=0:
                entityY=0
            elif entityY>=800:
                entityY=800
                
       
            
    
    
            
    class Predator(Animal):
        def __init__(Self):
            #super().__init__()
            Self.Img=pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
            Self.PredatorX=0
            Self.PredatorY=0
            Self.Screen= screen
            
            
        def Render(Self,Img,X,Y):
            Self.screen.blit(Img,(X,Y))
            
            
    
    
    
             
    class prey(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__():
            
            Self.preyImg=pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
            Self.preyX=300
            Self.preyY=700
            Self.PreyX_change=0
             
        def Render(Self):
            Self.screen.blit(preyImg,(preyX,preyY))
            
        def delete(Self):
            i.delete()
    
    
    
        
    CarrotImg=pygame.image.load('carrot.png')
    CarrotX=100
    CarrotY=300
    foodamount=7
    
    
    def food():
        #CarrotX=random.randint(10,950)
        #CarrotY=random.randint(10,750)
        screen.blit(CarrotImg,(CarrotX,CarrotY))
        
        
    
    #setup pygame
    pygame.init()
    
    #caption and Icons
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game Of Life")
    
    #predator icon
    
    predatorImg=pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
    predatorX=900
    predatorY=100
    predatorX_change=0
    
    
    #Prey Icon
    preyImg=pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
    preyX=300
    preyY=700
    PreyX_change=0
    
    
            
    #def delete():
            #prey.delete()
            
    preyImg=pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
    preyX=300
    preyY=700
    PreyX_change=0
    
    #def Prey():
        #screen.blit(preyImg,(preyX,preyY))
    class setup():
        def __init__():
            x=1
            
        def Predator1(Self):
            screen.blit(predatorImg,(predatorX,predatorY))
    
    #Finding closest prey
    def FindClosestItem(AgressorX,DefenderX,AgressorY,DefenderY):
        dist = math.sqrt((AgressorX-DefenderX)**2 + (AgressorY-DefenderY)**2)#finds distance in pixels
        
    
    #create pop out for game
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800))
    
    
    
    
    
    def Tracking(AgressorX,DefenderX,AgressorY,DefenderY):
        global XMovement#make variables global so it actually works
        global YMovement
        
        if AgressorX > DefenderX:#finds whether its position then moves left/righ,up/down depending on its location
            XMovement=-0.25
        
        elif AgressorX< DefenderX:
            XMovement=0.25
            
        else:
            XMovement=0
            
        
        if AgressorY > DefenderY:
            YMovement=-0.25
            
        elif AgressorY < DefenderY: 
            YMovement=0.25
            
        else:
            YMovement=0
            
            
    def EatPrey(predatorX,PreyX,predatorY,preyY):
        dist = math.sqrt((predatorX-preyX)**2 + (predatorY-preyY)**2)
        if dist < 20:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    
    #setup test
    
    predator=Predator()
    
    
    #Sprite groups
    all_sprites_Wolves=pygame.sprite.Group()
    
    
    all_sprites_Rabbits=pygame.sprite.Group()
    
    
    all_sprites_Carrots=pygame.sprite.Group()
    
        
    
    #game loop
    running=True
    while running:
    
        #Back ground colour
        screen.fill((0,128,0))
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                running=False
        
    
    
        
       
        
        predator.Render(pygame.image.load('Icon.png'),600,700)
        #Prey.Render()
    
        ClosestPrey=FindClosestItem(predatorX,preyX,predatorY,preyY)
        
        
        food()
        
        Track(predatorX,preyX,predatorY,preyY)
        predatorX+=XMovement
        predatorY+=YMovement
        #predatorX=BoundryX(predatorX)
        #predatorY=BoundryY(predatorY)
       
        
        Track(preyX,CarrotX,preyY,CarrotY)
        preyX+=XMovement
        preyY+=YMovement
        #preyX=BoundryX(preyX)
        #preyY=BoundryY(preyY)
        
    
        #Eat=EatPrey(preyX,preyY,predatorX,predatorY)
        
        #if Eat==True:
            #delete()
            #T=1
        
        #Boundry(prey)
        if preyX<=0:
            preyX=0
        elif preyX>=950:
            preyX=950
        if preyY<=0:
            preyY=0
        elif preyY>=750:
            preyY=750
            #preyY-=1
    
        #Boundry(predator)
        if predatorX<=0:
            predatorX=0
        elif predatorX>=950:
            predatorX=950
        elif predatorY<=0:
            predatorY=0
        elif predatorY>=750:
            predatorY=750
        pygame.display.update()
    
        timmer=timmer+1
```

Comment: Python is case-sensitive.   You have `Predator.Screen`, but are looking for `Predator.screen`.  Generally most people keep variable names lower case.  This is also what the Python Style Guide PEP8 recommends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is quite a mess, but don't worry, let's create a simple pygame game step for step. Try to understand what each step does.

First, let's start with a basic skeleton for a game, something like this:

```
import pygame

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        screen.fill('grey')
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here, we have a simple `main` function and a simple game loop that does nothing but listen for the `QUIT` event, make everything grey and limit the framerate to 60. You don't *have* to have a `main` function and the `__name__` check but doing this is good practice as it allows you to import file without running the game. Also, I helps to not pollute the global namespace.

OK, let's create some `Sprites`:

```
import pygame
from random import randint, choice

class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    colors = ['lightblue', 'blue', 'darkblue', 'dodgerblue']

    def __init__(self, pos=None, color=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill(color if color else choice(Animal.colors))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos if pos else (randint(100, 540), randint(100, 380)))

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    animals = pygame.sprite.Group()
    animals.add(Animal())
    animals.add(Animal())
    animals.add(Animal())

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        screen.fill('grey')
        animals.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To use the [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) class in pygame, the class needs an `image` attribute, which is a `Surface`, and a `rect` attribute, which is a [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and contains the position and the size of the `Surface`. If you create a `Sprite` like this, you can make use of the [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) class (or its subclasses) to draw and update your sprites. To draw somethin, I added three Animals to a group `animals` and call the `draw` function, passing the `screen` Surface as an argument so the `Group` knows where to blit the Animals' images.

[image]

Since this is quite boring so far, let's add some behaviour to our sprites:

```
import pygame
from random import randint, choice

class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    colors = ['lightblue', 'blue', 'darkblue', 'dodgerblue']

    def __init__(self, pos=None, color=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill(color if color else choice(Animal.colors))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos if pos else (randint(100, 540), randint(100, 380)))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(*self.rect.center)
        self.speed = 3
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))

    def update(self, dt):
        v = self.direction * self.speed
        while not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().contains(self.rect.move(v)):
            self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))
            v = self.direction * self.speed
        self.pos += v
        self.rect.center = self.pos

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock, dt = pygame.time.Clock(), 0
    
    animals = pygame.sprite.Group()
    animals.add(Animal())
    animals.add(Animal())
    animals.add(Animal())

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
                
        animals.update(dt/1000)
        
        screen.fill('grey')
        animals.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, we keep all the moving logic in the `Animal` class. The only thing that changed in the game loop is that we keep track of the *delta time* `dt` to ensure a constant frame rate (honestly, that's not that important in a small example like this, but again, good practice), and pass it to the groups `update` function, which in turn will call the `update` function of each sprite it contains.

In the Animal class, we use some simple vector math to move the sprite: we have a `speed` and a `direction` (which is a vector); and also an additional `pos` vector. Changing the position is easy with vectors because we can just do something like `pos = pos + direction * speed`, and changing the direction is simple too if we just randomly rotate the direction vector.

If you want to create a 2D game with moving parts I recommend that you learn a litte bit of vector math if you didn't already learn it in school. You don't need to know much more than the fact that you can easily add them up or multiply them etc.

Remember that the sprite is drawn at the coordinate of its `rect`, so we need to update the rect's position, too.

Pygame's `Rect` class has some handy functions, too. Just look how we check if the sprite would go out of screen. We can simply grab the `Rect` of the display surface, move the Sprite's `Rect` and check if it's still inside the screen rect. If not, we randomly rotate our `direction` vector (well, it's not 100% perfect, but KISS).

[image]

So what about other sprites? Let's just subclass our `Animal` class, change the speed and color and the behaviour by overwriting the update function:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
from random import randint, choice
from math import hypot

class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    colors = ['lightblue', 'blue', 'darkblue', 'dodgerblue']

    def __init__(self, pos=None, color=None, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.color = color if color else choice(Animal.colors)
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos if pos else (randint(100, 540), randint(100, 380)))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(*self.rect.center)
        self.speed = 3
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))

    def update(self, dt):
        v = self.direction * self.speed
        while not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().contains(self.rect.move(v)):
            self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))
            v = self.direction * self.speed
        self.pos += v
        self.rect.center = self.pos


class Preditor(Animal):
    
    def __init__(self, animals, pos=None, color=None, *grps):
        super().__init__(pos, color or 'red', *grps)
        self.speed = 4
        self.target = None
        self.animals = animals
        self.eaten = 0
        self.font = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 16)
        self.font.render_to(self.image, (10, 10), str(self.eaten), 'white')

    def get_nearest_animal(self):
        target = None
        distance = None
        for animal in self.animals:
            pygame.draw.line(pygame.display.get_surface(), 'darkgrey', self.pos, animal.pos)
            if not target:
                target = animal
                distance = hypot(animal.pos.x - self.pos.x, animal.pos.y - self.pos.y)
            else:
                new_distance = hypot(animal.pos.x - self.pos.x, animal.pos.y - self.pos.y)
                if new_distance < distance:
                    target = animal
                    distance = new_distance
        if target:
            pygame.draw.line(pygame.display.get_surface(), 'green', self.pos, target.pos)
        return target

    def update(self, dt):
        self.target = self.get_nearest_animal()
        if self.target:
            self.direction = (self.target.pos - self.pos).normalize()
        else:
            self.direction = pygame.Vector2(0, 0)
        
        self.pos += self.direction * self.speed
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        
        if self.target and self.rect.colliderect(self.target.rect):
            self.target.kill()
            self.image.fill(self.color)
            self.eaten += 1
            self.font.render_to(self.image, (10, 10), str(self.eaten), 'white')

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock, dt = pygame.time.Clock(), 0
    
    animals = pygame.sprite.Group()
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for _ in range(5):
        Animal(None, None, animals, all_sprites)
    Preditor(animals, None, None, all_sprites)

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                Animal(None, None, animals, all_sprites)
        
        screen.fill('grey')
        all_sprites.update(dt/1000)
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Sprites can be part of multiple groups, and we use that here to give the `Predator` a list of all its victims it can hunt and eat. Again, see how all sprite behaviour is inside the sprite classes. The only thing the main loop does is creating the initial state telling the sprite groups to update and draw all their sprites (and adding new Animals by pressing a key, because why not). Also note how we can use `kill` to remove it from all it groups, basically removing it from the game.

Hope that helps and gives you an idea on how to organize your pygame game.

Just play around a little. How about Animals that need to eat to stay alive and reproduce? And predators that will only need slower animals within reach, and if there are none, eat other predators or even plants?

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
from random import randint, choice
from math import hypot
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Plant(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    colors = ['green', 'lightgreen', 'darkgreen']

    def __init__(self, pos=None, color=None, *grps):
        self._layer = -10
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((24, 24))
        self.color = color if color else choice(Plant.colors)
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos if pos else (randint(10, 630), randint(10, 470)))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(*self.rect.center)

class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    font = None
    colors = ['lightblue', 'blue', 'darkblue', 'dodgerblue']

    def __init__(self, system, pos=None, color=None, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((24, 24))
        self.color = color if color else choice(Animal.colors)
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos if pos else (randint(100, 540), randint(100, 380)))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(*self.rect.center)
        self.speed = randint(20, 50) / 10
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))
        self.reproduce = randint(1, 5)
        self.sleep = 0
        self.eaten = 0
        self.energy = 10
        self.system = system
        if not self.font:
            Animal.font = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 16)

    def base_update(self, dt):
        self.energy -= dt * (self.speed / 2)
        if self.energy <= 0:
            self.kill()
            return False
    
        if self.sleep >= 0:
            self.sleep -= dt
            return False

        self.reproduce -= dt
        if self.reproduce <= 0 and self.energy >= 4:
            self.reproduce = randint(1, 7)
            self.__class__(self.system, self.pos, None, *self.groups())
            self.sleep = 0.5
            self.energy -= 1.5

        return True

    def update_image(self):
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.image.set_alpha(122 if self.sleep > 0 else 255)
            
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, 'green', (0, 0, self.rect.width * self.energy/10, 3))
        self.font.render_to(self.image, (7, 7), str(self.eaten), 'white')

    def get_nearest_target(self, targets, max_distance=250):
        target = None
        distance = None
        for possible_target in targets:
            if possible_target == self or hasattr(possible_target, 'speed') and possible_target.speed > self.speed:
                continue
            
            new_distance = hypot(possible_target.pos.x - self.pos.x, possible_target.pos.y - self.pos.y)
            pygame.draw.line(pygame.display.get_surface(), 'darkgrey' if new_distance > max_distance else 'white', self.pos, possible_target.pos)
            if new_distance <= max_distance:
                if not target or new_distance < distance:
                    target = possible_target
                    distance = new_distance
        if target:
            pygame.draw.line(pygame.display.get_surface(), 'green', self.pos, target.pos)
        return target

    def update(self, dt):
        if not self.base_update(dt) or len(self.groups()) == 0:
            return
            
        v = self.direction * self.speed
        while not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().contains(self.rect.move(v)):
            self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))
            v = self.direction * self.speed

        for plant in self.system.plants:
            if plant.rect.colliderect(self.rect) and self.energy < 8:
                plant.kill()
                self.eaten += 1
                self.energy = 10
                continue

        self.pos += v
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        self.update_image()

class Preditor(Animal):
    
    def __init__(self, system, pos=None, color=None, *grps):
        super().__init__(system, pos, color or 'red', *grps)
        self.speed = randint(20, 40) / 10
        self.target = None
        self.update_image()

    def update(self, dt):
        if not self.base_update(dt) or len(self.groups()) == 0:
            return

        self.target = self.get_nearest_target(self.system.animals)
        if not self.target:
            self.target = self.get_nearest_target(self.system.preditors)
        if not self.target:
            self.target = self.get_nearest_target(self.system.plants)
            
        if self.target:
            self.direction = (self.target.pos - self.pos).normalize()
        else:
            self.direction = pygame.Vector2(0, 0)
        
        self.pos += self.direction * self.speed
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        
        if self.target and self.rect.colliderect(self.target.rect):
            self.target.kill()
            self.eaten += 1
            self.sleep = 0.5
            self.energy += 3
            if self.energy > 10:
                self.energy = 10

        self.update_image()

@dataclass
class System:
    plants: object
    animals: object
    preditors: object

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock, dt = pygame.time.Clock(), 0

    GROW = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(GROW, 1000)

    
    animals = pygame.sprite.Group()
    plants = pygame.sprite.Group()
    preditors = pygame.sprite.Group()
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

    system = System(plants, animals, preditors)
    
    for _ in range(4):
        Animal(system, None, None, animals, all_sprites)

    for _ in range(5):
        Plant(None, None, plants, all_sprites)

    Preditor(system, None, None, preditors, all_sprites)

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                Animal(system, None, None, animals, all_sprites)
            if e.type == GROW:
                for _ in range(5):
                    Plant(None, None, plants, all_sprites)
        
        screen.fill('grey')
        all_sprites.update(dt/1000)
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]