# How can I assign rectangles unique values in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

In the past week I have downloaded pygame, and tried making different games, mainly following tutorials. As a project idea I have decided to make a game/simulation where mice and eagles move around the screen, eating, reproducing and trying to survive.

A vital part of the game is that each mouse must have individual information, like a variable for health, hunger and age. However, using my current code I am unware as to how I would do this, as I wish to have new mice spawn and added to a list of all the mice when certain events occur, with their individual info.

In other words, I am asking how I can give each 'given_mouse' unique variables that I can change when neccessary.

I have been trying different methods, and have done some googling but I have not yet come across a soloution, thanks in advance!

This is my code so far:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import sys
import os


def mouse_animation(given_mouse):
    global mouse_movement_counter, can_move_left, can_move_right, can_move_up, can_move_down


    if given_mouse.x <= 20:
        can_move_left = False

    if given_mouse.x >= 1100:
        can_move_right = False

    if given_mouse.y <= 20:
        can_move_up = False

    if given_mouse.y >= 600:
        can_move_down = False


    direction = random.randint(1, 4)

    if direction == 1 and mouse_movement_counter <= 0 and can_move_right:

        given_mouse.x += 60
        mouse_movement_counter += 30
        

    elif direction == 2 and mouse_movement_counter <= 0 and can_move_up: #UP

        given_mouse.y -= 60
        mouse_movement_counter += 30
        

    elif direction == 3 and mouse_movement_counter <= 0 and can_move_down:  # DOWN

        given_mouse.y += 60
        mouse_movement_counter += 30
        

    elif direction == 4 and mouse_movement_counter <= 0 and can_move_left:  # LEFT

        given_mouse.x -= 60
        mouse_movement_counter += 30
        
    elif direction == 5 and mouse_movement_counter <= 0:
        mouse_movement_counter += 30
    else:
        mouse_movement_counter -= 1

        

    
    pygame.display.update()


def random_postion():
    global x_location, y_location
    randomx_postion = random.randint(1,6)
    if randomx_postion == 1:
        x_location = 60
    if randomx_postion == 2:
        x_location = 120
    if randomx_postion == 3:
        x_location = 180
    if randomx_postion == 4:
        x_location = 240
    if randomx_postion == 5:
        x_location = 300
    if randomx_postion == 6:
        x_location = 360

    randomy_postion = random.randint(1,6)

    if randomy_postion == 1:
        y_location = 60
    if randomy_postion == 2:
        y_location = 120
    if randomy_postion == 3:
        y_location = 180
    if randomy_postion == 4:
        y_location = 240
    if randomy_postion == 5:
        y_location = 300
    if randomy_postion == 6:
        y_location = 360




pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

FPS = 10

screen_width, screen_height = 1160, 680

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

MOUSE_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "mouse.png"))


BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "background.png")), (screen_width,
                                                                                          screen_height))

mice = []

add_mouse = True

x_location = 0
y_location = 0

for i in range(40):
    random_postion()
    mouse = pygame.Rect(x_location, y_location, 40, 40)
    mice.append(mouse)

mouse_movement_counter = 0

while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(BG, (0, 0))

    for certain_mouse in range(len(mice)):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200, 200, 200), mice[certain_mouse])

    mouse_loop = 0

    while mouse_loop < len(mice):
        can_move_right = True
        can_move_left = True
        can_move_up = True
        can_move_down = True
        mouse_animation(mice[mouse_loop])
        mouse_loop += 1

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You should learn how classes work first; then maybe you find [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191469/having-issues-setting-up-and-displaying-the-sprites-in-my-classes-subclasses-in/65214006#65214006) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways I can think of. First one is to use a class for mouse.

```
class Mouse:
    def __init__(self, age, health, hunger):
        self.age = age
        self.health = health
        self.hunger = hunger

mice = []
if some_event_happens:
    mice.append(Mouse(some_age, some_health, some_hunger))
```

If you are not familiar with classes yet, you can use a 2D array.

```
mice = []
if some_event_happens:
    mice.append([some_age, some_health, some_hunger])
```

`mice[index]` gives you access to each mouse. `mice[index][0]` is age of mouse at that index, `mice[index][1]` is health of mouse at that index and mice`[index][2]` is hunger of mouse at that index.

Third way is to use a `dictionary`.

```
mice = []
if some_event_happens:
    mice.append({"age": some_age, "health": some_health, "hunger": some_hunger})
```

I would personally prefer to use this to 2D array because there is no ambiguity on what indices mean as words are used instead of number which is clearer. Example

```
mice[index]["age"]
```